# Is lazy evaluation required for do-notation?

Tags: programming-languages, language-design

[Do-notation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation) is most famous by Haskell, which is also famous for having lazy evaluation.

But is lazy evaluation *a requirement* for implementing do-notation?

In principle, could do-notation be added to imperative languages, such as Java and C++?

Comment: For the benefit of people who don't know Haskell, what is "do-notation"? It feels like a Java/C/whatever expert who doesn't know Haskell might be able to answer your question, if you explain what "do-notation" is.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I added a link, but I think to answer this question it would be best to already know Haskell (or FP) _and_ Java / C++.

Comment: OK -- that sounds reasonable. Thanks!

Comment: C#'s LINQ syntax and Scala's `for`-comprehensions are actual examples of `do`-notation equivalents in mainstream eager, imperative languages.

Answer (score 2):

It is not required that the language is lazy. The `do` notation exists in SML family of languages (for instance [OCaml](http://www.ocaml.org/)), which are eager. In these languages the `do`-notation is written as the `let`-notation, that is, instead of writing

```
do x1 <- e1
   x2 <- e2
   ...
   return e
```

we write

```
let x1 = e1 in
let x2 = e2 in
...
e
```

Note however that `let` in OCaml has a fixed monad (what in Haskell would be the IO monad), whereas the `do` notation in Haskell works for any monad. There are [extensions of OCaml](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/pull/1947) which allow you to use any monad.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, why not? F# is eager (not lazy) and has a [sort-of do-notation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Computation_Expressions).

Imperative PLs might add that as well, even if there's less need for monads there, since side effects (including mutating the values of variables) is a key aspect of those languages.

Scala has a `for` loop which resembles a monadic comprehension, so it's quite close to a do-block.